# Using TYPE_SHORT_GRAY for bufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage, java-2d

I have a scenario where,

I need to process an image which is signed 16-bit, from which i create a BufferedImage using **TYPE_USHORT_GRAY**.

As i mentioned it is Signed but java doesn't support **TYPE_SHORT_GRAY**.

also when i use,

```
DataBufffer d = bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer(); //bi is buffered image
```

**d** is obviously an instance of DataBufferUshort.

But i expect it to be an instance of DataBufferShort.

How can i create a BufferedImage of TYPE_SHORT_GRAY (Signed short).

Am new to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you use the ushort one instead? If Java doesn't support the type you want, what do you expect to do?

Answer (score 0):

To create a `BufferedImage` using signed `short` for backing, you need to create the `DataBuffer`/`Raster` yourself. There's no `TYPE_SHORT_GRAY` constant.

Try something like:

```
int w = 1600;
int h = 900;

// Create signed 16 bit data buffer, and compatible sample model
DataBuffer dataBuffer = new DataBufferShort(w * h);
SampleModel sampleModel = new ComponentSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_SHORT, w, h, 1, w, new int[] {0});

// Create a raster from sample model and data buffer
WritableRaster raster = Raster.createWritableRaster(sampleModel, dataBuffer, null);

// Create a 16 bit signed gray color model
ColorSpace colorSpace = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY);
ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(colorSpace, false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_SHORT);

// Finally create the signed 16 bit image
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);

System.out.println("image: " + image);
```